# The mean of Gaussian distribution subject to another Gaussian distribution, how to derive it？

Tags: normal-distribution, kalman-filter, matrix-inverse, inverse-gaussian-distribution

I got a fomula
$$N(y;cx,R)N(x;\bar{x},\Sigma)=N(y;c\bar{x},S)N(x;g,F)$$
where:

\begin{align}S&=c\Sigma c^T+R\\g &=\bar{x}+\Sigma c^Ts^{-1}(y-c\bar{x})\\F &= \Sigma - \Sigma c^T s^{-1} c \Sigma\end{align}

I want to know how to derive these fomula. 

--update--
I am sorry for ambiguous question.
$N(y;cx,R)N(x;\bar{x},\Sigma)$ means two gaussian distribution multiplying.
In each $N(y;cx,R)$, $cx$ is the mean and $R$ is the variance, and they are all matrix. 
$y$ in gaussian distribution means the random variable.

Comment: The question, as currently asked is not very clear. What does $N(y;cx,R)N(x;\bar x,\Sigma)$ mean for instance? Is $N(y;cx,R)$ the density at some point $y$ given a gaussian of mean $cx$ and variance $R$ for instance? When you put the two $N$'s next to one another, are you multiplying density?

Comment: Sorry for that, I have updated my question. Thank you.